# Altair two histograms in same plot, side-by-side bars

Tags: python, altair

I want to create an Altair histogram with side-by-side bars like this (except I want % per class, not count, on the Y axis):[image: Example two histograms]

This code is my current best guess for what to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

# Generate some example data
true_scores = np.random.normal(1, 2, 1000)
false_scores = np.random.normal(-2, 3, 1000)
scores = np.concatenate((true_scores, false_scores))
labels = [True] * 1000 + [False] * 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({"score": scores, "label": labels})

# make plot
alt.Chart(df).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='count(*)',
    groupby=['label']
).transform_calculate(
    pct='1 / datum.total'
).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X("label:N", axis=alt.Axis(title=None, labels=False)),
    y=alt.Y("sum(pct):Q", axis=alt.Axis(title="Count")),
    color=alt.Color('label:N'),
    column=alt.Column('score:Q', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=100), header=alt.Header(labelOrient="bottom")), 
)
```

[image: sad graph]

I don't know how to combine all of the separate facet column plots into a single plot. I've also tried much messier approaches of binning in Pandas, but those have other issues and still don't get me what I want.

Also, if people know of a cleaner way to get Percentage on the y axis, instead of count, please let me know.